# How to untangle Multiple iOS devices sharing one Apple ID for iMessage

Tags: iphone, ipad, messages, apple-id

I pay all our Internet bills and iPhone bills (3)/ just so you know when I ask this q I am not trying to get use off someone else's account.

We have a Mac, a Mac mini and MacBook

When I recvd my iphone, it synced with my husbands apple ID off his computer, now when I am asked for ID password I use his. (for app purchases etc)

I synced my new iPad 2 to my sons Mac mini, his ID is different, but I have his password also, as I said I pay it, so no one cares if I have their password.

I want to link my iPad 2 which I use all day long, to the iMessage app.
I was receiving my sons messages phone texts the day I started iMessage and I blocked it so I couldn't read them. I don't even remember how I blocked seeing them but I remember it was easy.
My question: can I sign into my iPad with his apple ID then list an added phone to see MY messages on my iPad imessage?

If it doesn't work I guess I could just delete the app and never use it?
My main concern is kicking my son off his texts on his phone.??

Comment: Do you have your own Apple ID that you use with your phone number for messaging? Or is it your husbands?

Comment: The Apple ID you use on your iPad can be anything. It doesn't have to be the same as the computer that it's synced to. Just go [here](https://appleid.apple.com/) to create your own Apple ID, and sign in to iMessages with that.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple people in one household can use the same Apple ID in iMessage.  That is how my wife and I have it setup.

On my devices, I have my phone number and email checked for iMessage.

On her devices, she has her phone number and email checked for iMessage.

**On the Mac, it is under Messages, Preferences.**

**On iOS, it is Settings, Messages, Send & Receive.**

Which messages are delivered to each device is dependant on which phone numbers and emails you have checked in the preferences listed above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a new account (if you don't already have one) for iMessage, and Facetime, and iCloud if you would. Apple IDs are free and easy to set up.

Do this on either device, and then login to your new Apple ID on the other device under Messages.

1. Go to Settings.app -> Messages -> Send & Receive
2. Tap: "Use your Apple ID for iMessage" or "Apple ID: [example]@me.com"
3. Create a new account or log into your own Apple ID.
4. Like mentioned above, log into your (new) Apple ID on your other device.

*Note:* both your iPhone and iPad must be on iOS 6 in order for messages to sync well. [This might help with information on how](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/77157/how-to-get-imessages-to-sync-across-an-iphone-ipad-and-mac-automatically) to set it up as well.